# 'Yet' in affirmative statements in American English (except in 'is yet to' and 'have yet to')

Tags: american-english

I know for a fact now that 'yet' is heard used in American English in affirmative statements like the following. 1 and 2 (and perhaps 3) are okay but 4. I just can't seem to see the rules with this. It has got to do with 'time' being early, and 'yet' has to be placed at the end of the sentence and right after the time expression. But I can't figure out why 4 is off.

1. A: We've got to hurry! B: Oh, calm down. It's early ***yet***.
2. A: Is he coming back soon? Has he finished his job in Beijing? B: No, he has two years ***yet***.
3. We have a long time ***yet***. We still can go to the gym.
4. We are only thirty minutes into the work ***yet***. But I'm already tired.

**Added queries**: (1) the word or phrase before 'yet' --- what would you say other than 'early' or the time expressions like 'two years,'a long time' etc.?
(2) Would you say, "There is three hours yet" to mean "We have three hours yet"?

Comment: *Yet* generally refers to time in the future, and the thirty minutes in 4 has already happened.

Comment: Does 4 sound idiomatic none the less to your ears?

Comment: Look up *yet* in a good dictionary and also check its use-cases. Good Luck.

Comment: Yet, it's a lot of effort to look in a dictionary Kris.

Comment: I did look that usage up in a large number of dictionaries, but it didn't yield a rule regarding how this 'yet' is used specifically. This entry has limitation in its use, it seems like.

Comment: I've never heard "yet" used like this.

Answer (score 8):

The adverbial *[yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yet)* stands at the junction of past and future, expressing the [persistence of action](http://linguapress.com/grammar/points/still-yet-already.htm) in time:

> ...used as an adverb, yet defines an action's persistence in time. The
>   word can define an action in the past, present or future:
>
> - I have never yet been late.
> - I yet stand.
> - I will yet arrive.
>
> <sub>Wikipedia.org</sub>

1. The first example from Wikipedia is persistence through the past into the present with implications of the future. Examining my past performance *I have never been late*, and that past performance offers an implicit promise of the future.
2. The second example is persistence in the present with implications of the past. *I am still standing*, but the larger context indicates that the past circumstances have not necessarily been favorable.
3. The third example is persistence in the future with implications of past and present. Through the past and up to the present, *I have not arrived*, but *I will eventually arrive* in the future.

---

The *[polarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item)* behavior of *[yet](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/adverbials-time/already-still-yet-and-no-longer)* requires a specific licensing context, which is a **pivot** between negative and positive polarity.  Toward the past *yet* tends to be a **negative polarity item**, but it tends to pivot into a **positive polarity item** toward the future. This polarity pivot can happen in the present, depending on its connection to the context of past and future. Examining the Wikipedia examples:

> 1. *I have never **yet** been late* expresses negative polarity in the past and in the present--*I have **never** been late* and implies a pivot to positive polarity toward the future--[*I will continue that performance*].
> 2. *I **yet** stand* implies negative polarity toward the past--[***Against*** implied opposition]--and expresses a pivot to positive
>      polarity in the present--*I stand.*
> 3. *I will **yet** arrive* implies negative polarity toward the past and in the present--[*Though I have **not** arrived*], and expresses a pivot to
>      positive polarity toward the future--*I will arrive.*

---

Examining the polarity of *[yet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yet)* in definitions at Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> adverb
>
> 1.0 Up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then:
>   *I have**n’t** told anyone else **yet***
>   *are**n’t** you ready to go **yet**?*
>   *I have **yet** to be convinced*
>
> *<sub>**Emphasis** added</sub>*

The expressed polarity toward the past is consistently negative, and a pivot to positive polarity toward the future is consistently expressed or implied, while the polarity in the present is determined by its connection to past and future.

- I haven't told anyone, [**but** I may tell someone in the future].
- You may not be ready to go yet, [**but** you may be ready in the future].
- [I am not convinced], **but** may be convinced in the future

> [WITH SUPERLATIVE]: *the congress was widely acclaimed as the best **yet***
>
> *<sub>**Emphasis** added</sub>*

Within the historical perspective of the statement, the comparison of the "current" congress to those of the past creates a negative polarity toward the past and pivots to positive polarity in the present.

- [Other congresses were **not** as good], **but** this one is the best.

> 1.1 [WITH NEGATIVE] As soon as the present or a specified or implied time:
>   *wait, do**n’t** go yet*
>
> *<sub>**Emphasis** added</sub>*

The polarity in the present is expressed as negative, while the pivot to a positive polarity toward the future is implied--[*you may go in the future*].

> *I hope to continue for some time **yet***
>
> *<sub>**Emphasis** added</sub>*

An negative polarity in the present is implied--[*there are forces that might oppose my hope*] and *yet* pivots to a positive polarity toward the future.

> 1.3 Referring to something that will or may happen in the future:
>   *further research may yet explain the enigma* 
>   *I know she’s alive and I’ll find her yet*

The polarity toward the past or in the present is implied as negative--[*past research has not explained the enigma*]...[*there may be reasons to believe she is dead*], and *yet* pivots to positive polarity toward the future.

> 2.0 Still; even (used to emphasize increase or repetition):
>   snow, snow, and yet more snow
>   yet another diet book
>   the rations were reduced
>   yet again
>
> 3.0 In spite of that; nevertheless: every week she gets worse, and yet it could go on for years

The positive-negative comparisons create a pivot, extending the normal licensing context for *yet*.

---

Examining the examples of the OP:

> 1. A: We've got to hurry! B: Oh, calm down. It's early **yet**.

The context implies a negative polarity in the present rush and pivots to a positive polarity toward the future.

> 2. A: *Is he coming back soon? Has he finished his job in Beijing?* B: ***No***, he has two years **yet**.

*No* creates a negative polarity in the present time frame, and *yet* pivots into a positive polarity toward the future--*he will come back after two years*.

> 3. *We have a long time **yet**. We still can go to the gym.*

The context implies a negative polarity in the present time frame--[*we **don't** need to go to the gym now*], and *yet* pivots into a positive polarity toward the future--*we can go to the gym sometime in the future*.

> 4. *We are only thirty minutes into the work yet. But I'm already tired.*

*Only* creates a negative polarity toward the past and the conjunction *but* extends the negative polarity in the present, but the necessary pivot into a positive polarity is missing. The pivot would have been expressed by *yet* as a conjunction, if the sentence had been written:

> *We are only thirty minutes into the work, yet I'm already tired* .

---

**Conclusion**

In the OP, the fourth example is not idiomatic--even thought the definitions fit-- because the context defies the licensing context for *yet*, which expresses or implies a ***pivot*** in polarity between past, present and future.

Comment: I made a group of sentences, considering the polarity change. What do you think of it? It goes from negative to positive --- 'don't have to stay' to 'have to stay':

It's only 10:00 am. I can go to the gym yet, but I need to stay at home from 2:00 pm. My kids come back home early today.

Comment: It's encouraging, @Sssamy, to see you experimenting with the use of *yet* and the concept of polarity. Can you identify the polarity **pivot** that actually serves as the licensing context for *yet* in your sentences?

Comment: @ScotM, my intended pivot is from 'I don't have to say at home (so I could go to the gym)' to 'I have to stay home.' It's negative to positive, isn't it? I'm hoping my understanding of the word 'pivot' is okay.

Comment: The pivot I perceive is in the present from the negative [It's not too late], implied by the word ***only*** in the expression *it's only 10:00 AM*, to the positive future:  *I can go to the gym.* That future boundary of 2:00 PM, which informs the present deadline presents a very interesting complexity that seems to stretch *yet* into a broader usefulness, but the glory of English semantics and syntax is its reasonable flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

In the fourth sentence, *yet* almost means *so far*.

*We are only thirty minutes into the work **so far**.*

In the previous sentences, *yet* conveyed the meaning of *still*. Try substituting 'so far' in these sentences, you'll find that they make no sense.

In my opinion, *still* or *yet*(especially in the second and the third sentences) convey that there is still something in stock, for the future(For ex:  *He has two years yet*.(his completion of two years is a part of the future))

*So far* or *yet* as used in the last sentence makes me think about the past(For ex: We are only thirty minutes into the work yet.(we have successfully worked through thirty minutes only))

You can use this [link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yet?s=t) to find the different definitions of *yet*.

Think about it and let me know if the information that I provided helped.

Comment: So to your ears, does 4 sound fine, except it doesn't mean 'still' but 'so far'?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely! Among the many synonyms of 'yet', you'll find 'so far' . I think that explains the usage of 'yet' as 'so far' in some contexts.

Comment: @AishwaryaAR: To save the OP the trouble, maybe you could provide a reference which supports your statement. It's a good practice to add references, even for words which seem common. I'm sure you've seen answers like that.

Comment: I ask because I'm kind of on the fence in this case.

Comment: (Started writing this before Tushar but uploaded after him) Okay, great. Suppose you are to work five hours, and that you have worked four hours and thirty minutes. Would you still say 'We are four hours and a half into the work yet'? No, you wouldn't, right? the word means 'so far' but it still has a tone of 'There is plenty of time ahead,' right? And is this usage of 'yet,' as in 4, also American?

Comment: I think that it's because of a previous reference to five hours that you feel 'We are four hours and a half into the work yet' doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Right. If it's 'so far,' it works perfectly because it doesn't convey a sense of much ahead. But 'yet' still has that undertone, doesn't it? Is this American? Do you have North American ears?

Comment: Yes, you're right. 'Yet' when used as 'so far' has a slight 'still' undertone.(it really depends on the way you think about the situation). I really cannot tell if this usage of 'yet' is North American(only a native English speaker can tell you and I'm not a native speaker). Sorry!

Comment: @TusharRaj: Unfortunately, the source was just the same Google search that I'd described earlier :P. Most of my answer is made up of opinions(which are hopefully right).

Comment: @AishwaryaAR: That's what I'm trying to tell you. Opinion-based answers aren't considered good ones here. Even if you are sure, it doesn't hurt to take a couple of minutes to add links to definitions from your favorite online dictionary. There are plenty.

Comment: @TusharRaj: I hope it's better now.

Comment: @TusharRaj, I understand why you are inclined to sit on the fence. It seems that two untrained ears are hearin an unidiomatic expression to be "just fine"! Do you have any sense that these two students are willing to understand, or are they just looking for arbitrary rules to suit their untrained ears?

Comment: @ScotM: I understand that your answer is factual and my answer is mostly opinion-based but that doesn't mean I was looking for 'arbitrary rules'. I haven't even stated rules in my answer! In fact, I've mentioned 'In my opinion' which was supposed to make things clear. I'm sure my answer made sense.

Comment: +1 Actually, @AishwaryaAR, your answer makes perfect sense :) It was a response to the direct question : *So to your ears, does 4 sound fine, except it doesn't mean 'still' but 'so far'?*. Your response was:  *Yes! Absolutely!*  In light of your good answer, that response seemed strange to me too. I understand the usage of *yet* is actually broadening, but it seems wise for people to perceive that shift in the context of the historical usage. It really would be a shame to loose the nuance of *yet* completely.